# EXTJS Dynamic FlowChart

Tags: extjs, dynamic, flowchart

Like I have a if then else, and I want a flowchart for it?
Let me explain more, can it be possible, that my server generate some dynamic conditions as input and it draw flowchart for me in extjs 4.
ex: if a>b and a

Comment: Please put a little more effort in your questions. And maybe you should read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

This is the first result on Google and looks like exactly what you want:
http://www.cubedrive.com/flowPublic?id=HQypsxuhMgQ_&viewStatus=publicView

Comment: My server side will generate some if then else condition and I want a corresponding flowchart on my screen (in extjs 4).

Comment: That's exactly what this does.